# Overloaded << operator doesn't work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unique-ptr

I have a question regarding the overloaded `<<` operator.

I have a class named `House` in which I have defined the following (I didn't declare it as `friend` and it's a free 'function' because I'm not going to access private members):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, House const& house)
{
    // Append strings to 'stream'
    return stream
}
```

In another class, I have this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<House>> houses
```

Now, I want to iterate through my `vector` and display the houses, and I have 2 questions!

My first question: is there a way to iterate through my `vector` of `unique_ptr` using the foreach loop, because it doesn't seem that I can do: `for (auto house : houses) { /* Do stuff */ }`

Second question: If I iterate using a normal `for` loop, and I do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < houses.size(); i++)
{
    cout << *houses[i].get() << endl;
}
```

I receive an error saying that **no operator << matches the operands**. Can you please tell me what I'm missing?

## Update

Thank you all for your answers, the iteration using `auto&` helped a lot, and the reason for my other problem was that I was defining my overloaded operator in my `House.cpp` file. Since I was doing the `#include` for my `House.h`, it wasn't able to see the overloaded operator. Stupid mistake!

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] instead of pseudo code please, otherwise you question cannot receive concise answers.

Comment: `for (auto& house : houses)`

Comment: You don't need to do `*houses[i].get()`. `std::unique_ptr<>` overloads the dereference operator so you can simply do `*houses[i]`.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to guess what the problem with the operator is. Did you declare it before the for loop? Is it in a different namespace than your House class?

Comment: I updated the question and explained what I was missing. Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Iterating through the vector of `unique_ptr`:

```
for (auto& phouse : houses) {  // phouse is a referetence to a unique_ptr
     /* Do stuff using    *p  or p->xxx */ 
}
```

*Remark: The trick with the `auto&` means that the loop will use (by reference) the pointers in the vector. With `auto` only,  the compiler would try to copy the `unique_ptr` into the loop variable, which is forbidden for `unique_ptr`.*

I couldn't reproduce the error of your second question.  At least not after adding the missing `;` .   By the way, you don't need `get()`: you can dereference immediately

Here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/xwnp7e)